# How to update dmc header not using UI component use python code

Tags: python, plotly-dash

```py
dmc.Container(
    children=[
        dmc.Header(height=30,
                   children=[
                       dmc.Text("This header"),
                   ],
                   id='header',
                   style={"backgroundColor": "#9c86e2"}),
        dcc.Graph(id='live-update-graph', 
                  style={'height': '300px', 'width':'800px'}, 
                  config={'displayModeBar': False},),
    ] 
)

@app.callback(Output("header", "children"), Input("text", "value"))
def update_header(text):
    return dmc.Text(text)

def update_header_thread():
    while True:
        update_header("test")
        sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data_thread = threading.Thread(target=update_header_thread)
    data_thread.daemon = True
    data_thread.start()
    app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

I want to change `dmc.Header` using `update_header` function which is called in a thread.
But it does not work.
Please help.

I try to add id to `dmc.Text`, and set output to `dmc_text`, still not work.

```py
dmc.Header(height=30,
                   children=[
                       dmc.Text("This header", id="dmc_text"),
                   ],
                   id='header',
                   style={"backgroundColor": "#9c86e2"}),


@app.callback(Output("dmc_text", "children"), Input("text", "value"))
def update_header(text):
    return dmc.Text(text)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.